# Go HTTP handler - handling more than two form actions

Tags: go

I have a webapp where I have code like:

```
func handler (w res, r req) {
  if req.Method == POST {
    // create html form 2 with a submit button2
    return ;
  }
  // create html form 1 with a submit button1
  return
} 

func main() {
  handle("/", handler)
}
```

Now, the root / is registered with the handler func. In the first request (GET), I create a form and send it to the user. If the user submits this form, I handle it under the "POST" method. Now, I create a different form in the post method handler, and now I want a way to do some operations based on what the user typed in this form2, when [s]he submits form2.

What is the standard way with go to handle the form2 form submission ? I have done some asp programming earlier and we use form action to submit to a different asp file. How can I do some actions based on parsing the form2 submission request ?

Comment: If you use the form action, you can register different handlers. Or you can make a swich based on parameter values. I'm not sure I get what is the problem. Are you asking for a guideline or some predefined framework ?

Comment: I am asking for a guideline on how to do this best. In all the examples I have seen, it is via an if clause in the handler, where the first will be to check if the method name is post, then the submit content is handled, and if it is not, it is the first form-creation page. I could not find any examples for webpages with 3 actions. If you can give some sample code for handling such 3 actiosn (initial form load, handling that form submit + creating another form in teh response, handling the second form), it will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Please show us your HTML code for your three forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want a way of routing the same URL to different handlers based on the request *method* rather than just the path? If that's the case...

For comparison, using Python + Django, the way you're doing this is pretty standard:

```
def my_django_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try_to_process_posted_data()
    elif request.method == "GET":
        show_a_form_to_user()
```

If you are trying to do fancier things like URL routing based on path **and** request method (GET, POST, DELETE, ...), then you might be interested in something like [Gorilla.mux](http://gorilla-web.appspot.com/pkg/gorilla/mux/)

It provides some friendly URL routing methods:

```
func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/", YourGETHandlerFunc).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/", YourPOSTHandlerFunc).Methods("POST")
    http.Handle("/", router)
}
```

If you're looking for more resources for web development...

- Mango: http://paulbellamy.com/2011/05/introducing-mango/
- Web.go: http://www.getwebgo.com/tutorial
- Twister: https://github.com/garyburd/twister/blob/master/examples/hello/main.go